# System Stack error doing the merge sort algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Am doing the merge sort alg using recursion, which is probably the cause of the stack overflow. I have searched but can't seem to find out what part of the code is causing all of this.

Here's my code:

```
  def merge(arr)
    return arr if arr.length <= 1
    mid = arr.length/2
      x = arr[0..mid]
      y = arr[mid..-1]
      merge_sort(merge(x),merge(y))
    end

    def merge_sort(left, right)
      sorted = []
      while left.length > 0 && right.length > 0
        if left.first > right.first
          sorted << left.shift
        else
          sorted << right.shift
        end
    end
      sorted.concat(left).concat(right)
    end


nums = 15.times.map {rand(100) + 1}
puts merge(nums)
```

In the terminal I get: merge-sort.rb:2: Stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby `...` is endpoint exclusive, and `..` is endpoint inclusive.
That means your `x`, and `y` both contains `arr[mid]` .

Change

```
x = arr[0..mid]
```

to

```
x = arr[0...mid]
```

and it should work.

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Range.html